# how to show two values in two different textbox using ajax in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have 3 pages, I want to do that when I enter name in textbox. Email and Phone display in different textbox using ajax. It displays both values in 1 textbox but I want both values in two different textboxes.

**HTML**
This is my html page:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : Test
    Created on : Oct 10, 2017, 9:59:46 PM
    Author     : Lenovo
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>


    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="NameDB.jsp" method="post" name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="dynamic_field">
        <tr>
        <th>Enter Name</th>
        <th>Enter email</th>
        </tr>    

        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name_1" placeholder="Enter Name" size="25" class="searchName" id="search1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email_1" id="esearch1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone_1" id="psearch1"/></td>
        <td>
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add More</button>    
        </td>
        </tr>  


        </table>    
        <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit"/>       
        </form>
```

**JQuery**
This is my Jquery and Ajax

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i=1;
    $('#add').click(function()
    {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" id="search'+i+'" class="searchName" name="name_'+i+'" placeholder="Enter Name"/></td>\n\
    <td><input type="text" id="esearch'+i+'" class="searchEmail" name="email_'+i+'"/></td>\n\
    <td><input type="text" id="psearch'+i+'" class="searchPhone" name="phone_'+i+'" placeholder="Enter Phone"/></td>\n\
    <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>\n\
    <td><input type="hidden" name="count" value="'+i+'"/></td></tr>');

    });


    $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function()
    {
       var button_id=$(this).attr("id");
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();

    });

    $(document).on('change','.searchName',function()
    {
       var id=$(this).attr("id");
       var name=$('#'+id).val();
       //var email=$('#e'+id).val();

     $.ajax({
        url:"AjaxDB.jsp",
        type:"post",
        dataType:"text",
        data:{name:name},
        cache:false,
        success:function(data)
        { 

         //$('#show').html(data);  
         $('#e'+id).val(data);
        }
        });
        });

    });
```

**AjaxDB.JSP**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
        <%
        try
        {
          String name=request.getParameter("name");
          String email=null;
          String phone=null;
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm","root","root");
          Statement st=con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs;          
          rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test where name='"+name+"'");
          while(rs.next())
          {
              email=rs.getString("email");
              phone=rs.getString("phone");

              out.print(email);
              out.print(phone);


          }        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to receive data from server, then it is recommend to use JSON. You are sending data as plain text from "AjaxDB.JSP"
2. If response is by using JSON, then you should Servlet instead of JSP page.
   Both following points are explained through code:

Your servlet code might be following:

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;  
import java.io.*;  
import org.json.simple.*;

public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)  
    throws ServletException,IOException  
    {
        res.setContentType("application/json");//setting the content type  
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();//get the stream to write the data  
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        try {
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm","root","root");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;          
            rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test where name='"+name+"'");
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
            while(rs.next()) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("email",rs.getString("email"));
                obj.put("email",rs.getString("phone"));
                list.add(obj);
            }
            response.put("response", list);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        pw.println(response.toJSONString());
        pw.close();//closing the stream  
    }
}
```

And your client side code can be following:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"AjaxDB.jsp",
    type:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{name:name},
    cache:false,
    success:function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.response[0].email);
            console.log(data.response[0].phone);
        }
    });
});
```

Special Note: The code is untested. So debug if any error found!